# Alternative to Excel userform in google sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets-api

Been looking around and can't find an answer..

I have to create a piece of work. where several users create a "Order" that then gets submitted into a database sheet.

In Microsoft excel I would usually create a button that opens up a userform with my various fields that need to be entered, the user would then click submit.

When submitting it would check the data and then if all ok add it to a tab within the workbook.

I am trying to replicate this in google sheets.. any ideas?

I looked at google forms but that doesn't really work as the user would need to see what was previously submitted (Hence why I liked to use MS excel userforms as it is a pop up)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/) currently doesn't support this. Check out [Forms Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/) if it suits your purpose. Try to file a [feature request here](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?) also.